# How do I traverse the graph given a start point and without knowledge of the final one?

Tags: gremlin, orientdb, tinkerpop

Suppose I have a graph that looks like a tree of variable arity. I have the `Vertex` and I don't know anything about whereabouts of the final point except that it's `id` is `0`. I've seen some examples of the Gremlin usage, but can't find a suitable one - they all basically do something like `x.out.in.out` and so on, and that's inapplicable in my case. I also use the Java bindings, so I'd be grateful if your anwers came with respect to that fact.

P.S. Maybe I should be more specific. I'd also like to collect all the `properties` of that nodes, so if there is some kind of a `reduce`/`foldLeft` etc, but only for `pipe`s - that'd be just great.

Answer (score 0):

Example for the [Tinkerpop Toy Graph](https://github.com/tinkerpop/blueprints/wiki/Property-Graph-Model) (find a path from vadas [vertex 2] to peter [vertex 6]):

```
gremlin> g = TinkerGraphFactory.createTinkerGraph()
==>tinkergraph[vertices:6 edges:6]
gremlin> start = g.v(2)
==>v[2]
gremlin> end = g.v(6)
==>v[6]
gremlin> start.as("x").both().loop("x", {it.object != end}, {true}).retain([end]).path()[0]
==>[v[2], v[1], v[3], v[6]]
```

The query is not optimal and will run forever if you don't restrict the number of results, but it should answer your question.

If you want all properties:

```
gremlin> start.as("x").both().loop("x", {it.object != end}, {true}).retain([end]).path().transform({ it.collect({ it.map() }) })[0]
==>[{age=27, name=vadas}, {age=29, name=marko}, {name=lop, lang=java}, {age=35, name=peter}]
```

And if you just need a single property:

```
gremlin> start.as("x").both().loop("x", {it.object != end}, {true}).retain([end]).path().transform({ it.collect({ it.name }) })[0]
==>[vadas, marko, lop, peter]
```

Cheers,
Daniel

Comment: Thank you Daniel. What does `both` mean? I mean, what's it analog in Java API, `bothV`?

Comment: See: http://www.tinkerpop.com/docs/javadocs/gremlin/2.4.0/com/tinkerpop/gremlin/java/GremlinPipeline.html#both(java.lang.String...)